# Sum of Terms of a Unit Vector

Tags: summation, vectors

Say I have some unit vector $\{c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_t\}$ where $c_j\in \mathbb{R}$ and $c_j\leq 1$ for all $j$. Also, as it is a unit vector $\sum_{j=0}^t c_j^2=1$. Now define $\rho\equiv \sum_{j=0}^{t-1}c_{j}c_{j+1}$. Is $|\rho|\leq 1$ true? Is $|\rho|<1$ true? I've tried this via induction but it seems to go nowhere. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
|\rho| = \left| \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} c_j c_{j+1} \right| \leq \left( \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} c_j^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{t} c_j^2 \right)^{1/2} \leq 1,
$$
which proves the non-strict inequality.

For the strict inequality, suppose we actually had $|\rho| = 1$.  Then we must have $c_1 = c_t = 0$, because otherwise the second inequality above would be strict.  But also, equality holds in the first inequaliy above (the Cauchy-Schwarz step) iff $c_{j+1} = ac_j$ for some constant $a$.  But since $c_1 = c_t = 0$ this would imply that each $c_j = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I really like this, but how does one claim that $c_{j+1}=a c_j$ iff $\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}c_jc_{j+1}$ is less than the norms of the two vectors? I can see that if $c_{j+1}=ac_j$ we'd get that, but not the other way around.

Comment: @KenRobbins It's a standard follow up to the usual statement of Cauchy-Schwarz.  See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proofs)

Comment: very well explained. I had just never run across that! Thank you.